# Using GCM dependant library for an app using fcm

Tags: android, sdk, google-cloud-messaging, android-library, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a library developer(SDK) and my SDK is using `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'` which is working properly with apps using GCM, but it crashes every time when the App receives push from FCM/GCM,
Is it a good idea to use GCM librery for apps with FCM? are there any work-arounds to stop the crash? I am not able to receive notification from GCM/FCM
Library build.gradle:

```
android {
enforceUniquePackageName = false
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 18
    resConfig "en"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.2'
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"></uses-sdk>

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!--  Required if we need to invalidate access tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <!--other permissions-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!--GCM services starts here-->
        <!--
       WakefulBroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
       services and hand them to the custom IntentService.

       The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
       so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
     -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.xyz.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".NgageGcmIntentService" />
        <!--GCM services ends here-->

        <!--<activity-->
            <!--android:name="com.xyz.messaging.ChatActivity"-->
            <!--android:label="@string/app_name"-->
            <!--android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"-->
            <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme"-->
            <!--android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.xyz.ui.ImageViewer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.xyz.messaging.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

        <service
            android:name="com.xyz.gcm.PNListenerService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.xyz.gcm.GCMInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Sample App build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.sample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 3
        versionName "0.3"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
   compile project(':gcm')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Sample App Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xyz.sample">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.xyz.messaging.ChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.xyz.sample.DeepLinkedActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="com.ndtv"
                    android:pathPrefix="/pushnotification"
                    android:scheme="ndtv" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="gcm_launching_activity"
            android:value="com.xyz.sample.MainActivity" />
        <service
            android:name=".FCMMessageRecieverService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

       <!-- <meta-data
            android:name="gcm_enable_notification_access"
            android:value="disable" />-->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What error????? Include stacktrace

Comment: @Polarbear0106 Thanks for reply, I added the stack-trace..

Comment: It cannot find the cloud messaging. Did you compile everything right?

Comment: @Polarbear0106 yes, i did, same library works for an app without FCM perfectly....

Comment: Are you using any other firebase dependencies? Also could you try with 9.2.0 and include the request you are using to send the message?

Comment: Please add the full gradle dependency block you are using.

Comment: Hi @ArthurThompson, I was able to resolve the crash by adding a validate method on my broadcast receiver, but now, i am not able to display notifications...

Comment: Looks like you are using FCM and GCM in the same project, this should not be done. Use one or the other.

Comment: @ArthurThompson, Mine is a library project which uses gcm(I'll migrate to FCM soon, there are some backend issues) .. But i am (for a time being) looking for alternatives and some work arounds to continue provide the service for apps

Comment: Use this - https://github.com/karanatwal/FirePush